# OpenShift rhc port-forward add port

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

I am new to OpenShift, and trying to run elasticsearch in a DIY cartridge. The elasticsearch app seems to be working, but I cannot connect to the 3306 port which it needs for node to node communication.

When I run the

```
$ rhc port-forward -a myapp

Forwarding ports ...
To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the local address
Service Local          OpenShift
------- -------------- ------------------------
java    127.0.0.1:3306 => 127.10.49.101:3306
java    127.0.0.1:9200 => 127.10.49.101:9200
```

But when I run my indexing groovy/grails app that uses an elasticsearch plugin to index data, it cannot connect to the OpenShift elasticsearch node. It should be using port 3306 to connect to the OpenShift elasticsearch node. The app config has

```
client.node = 'node'
client.hosts = [ [host:'127.0.0.1', port:3306 ] ]
```

Note that my indexing app worked fine when elasticsearch was run locally, but it does not connect to elasticsearch running on OpenShift.

Comment: In your command output, port 3306 is already added. 127.0.0.1:3306 => 127.10.49.101:3306. Can you please clarify more?

Comment: Sorry, my original question was not clear. The problem is that my local indexing app is creating a local node, and it cannot join the OpenShift elasticsearch node. It is set to use port 3306 for node-to-node communication.